# Most efficient way to transform a JS React app/widget into a public shopify-app on the Shopify store

Tags: python, reactjs, shopify, shopify-app

I have developed a ReactJS app/widget whose code is hosted on my cloud server (AWS) and that can be integrated onto any E-Commerce website.

The objective of the widget/plugin is to help buyers on the E-Commerce website choose the best product to buy from the proposed product listing of the E-Commerce website.

I have developed an SDK in JS that allows us to integrate that widget/plugin onto any E-Commerce website by calling the function  called `createWidget` from the E-Commerce website.

The API backend of the plugin and its functions are done in Python/Flask.

I am interested in putting my application onto the shopify store to allow any potential user to easily integrate my plugin onto their e-commerce website.

My question is: What is the best course of action to take to host my app onto the shopify store? I suppose that involves transforming my plugin into an embedded public shopify-app? What is the most efficient way to do so without restarting the whole project/code from scratch? (i.e. keeping the same source code developed in React JS and the SDK)

I am open to proposals, suggestions, links, etc.

Thank you

Comment: Your question lacks context and focus and clarity.

Comment: @DavidLazar Thank you for your feedback. I have just added additional information to try and better explain. I remain open if this is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

One, your App needs to be installable in a Shopify store. So you have to add the correct OAuth calls for that and ask for the appropriate permissions for the resources you work with (products). Two, you would create an extension into Shopify that would interact with Themes. That would allow merchants to drag-drop your widget into their theme, placing it where they like. Your widget thus becomes a nice little handy unit the merchant can easily work with.

That is all you have to do. Nothing scary. Nothing hard to do. Standard stuff.